# Is it possible to attach maven snapshots as dependencies using Android Studio?

Tags: maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have declared maven snapshots in repositories, but lib is not visible:

```
repositories {
....
maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.lyft:reactivehttp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I tested my snapshot with maven project and it working fine.

Comment: The script seems to be correct.
I am not an expert about packaging but in this snapshot I can see <packaging>pom</packaging>.
May be it should be a jar instead of pom.

Comment: It was pom. But it should be jar right now.

Comment: Are you still having problems? This works fine for me.